# Any idea why this payline secure form doesn't work?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, gateway

These are the values and then the has key create base on that which looks correct in my opinion

```html
<form action="https://secure.paylane.com/order/cart.html" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="EUR" />
    <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="20235" />
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="Subscription" />
    <input type="hidden" name="transaction_description" value="Subscription" />
    <input type="hidden" name="transaction_type" value="S" />
    <input type="hidden" name="back_url" value="http://someurl" />
    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="66f84f0a5dc54d810f121d20417331e78f79d153" />

    <button type="submit">Pay with PayLane</button>
</form>
```

but paylane give this error [image]

Answer (score 0):

Test it in online php interpreters. Does it shows exactly same hash as your in example. For example on http://ideone.com/ or http://phptester.net/

```
<?php
  $salt = "your salt"; 
  $description = "Subscription";
  $amount = "20";
  $currency = "EUR";
  $merchant_id = "20235";
  $transaction_type = "S";
  $hash = SHA1("$salt|$description|$amount|$currency|$transaction_type");
echo $hash;
```

I used `"tro8ne9c"` salt word. And Hash was `"bfbda60a4061f38cea872e4ee29b5dbfa30870a8"`. Which was correctly recognized by Paylane.com

Comment: my salt is "ta3mu3bi" and I generate it in a same way :|

Comment: My Merchant ID was my Login. Is `20235` your login?

Comment: So it is not the Id I have in my secure form! I will try it .